# SQL query to return 1 if the day is the last day of month or else return 0

Tags: sql

SQL query to return 1 if the day is the last day of month or else return 0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is best to also post what you have tried so far and what error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can do:

```
select (case when extract(day from (datecol + interval '1' day)) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end)
```

That is, add one day and check the day-of-the-month.

Date functions are notoriously database specific, so the exact logic probably depends on your database.

EDIT:

I realize the question is not about a date column but about the current date.  You can handle that as:

```
select (case when extract(day from (current_date + interval '1' day)) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end)
```

Comment: I think this is a very clever workaround for a database-agnostic answer!  I would just note that it does depend on the datecol being an actual DATE type column and not stored as a VARCHAR or other non-date format.